# Creating new pages in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I created the file and even added the code to the items_controller file (which I learned since not having to do it in regular PHP) but still getting a message that the new page is not found.

http://neighborrow.com/items/create/

The error must be in the `items_controller` file because it's working in debug mode, but when I list an item it's showing the confirm message I copied from the items/add page even though I edited it for create:

```
    function create()
    {
        if(!empty($this->data))
        {
            if (!empty($this->data))
            {
                $user_error = false;
                $this->Item->create();
                if($this->Auth->user())
                {
                    $user_id = $this->Auth->User('id');
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!$user_id = $this->Item->User->is_user($this->data['Item']['user_email']))
                    {
                        $email = $this->data['Item']['user_email'];

                        // Create Password
                        $raw_password = $this->PasswordHelper->generatePassword();

                        // Has Password
                        $hashed_password = $this->Auth->password($raw_password);

                        // Add User
                        if (!$user_id = $this->Item->User->add_basic($email, $hashed_password))
                            $user_error = true;

                        // Login the User
                        $this->Auth->login(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $hashed_password));

                        // Send Registration Email
                        $this->Email->send_registration_email($email, $raw_password);
                    }
                }
                if(!$user_error)
                {
                    $this->data['Item']['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    $this->data['Item']['approved'] = 1;
                    if ($this->Item->save($this->data))
                    {
                        $this->Session->setFlash('Congratulations on your first listing! After we review it to make sure it is rentable, we will send you your free profile where you can list, promote, and rent up to nine more items.   Feel free to share you new listing right away! <a name="fb_share" type="button_count" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>.');
                        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'items', 'action' => 'view', $this->Item->id));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try setting Configure::write('debug', 1); in config/core.php so you can see the error message from CakePHP.

Comment: http://neighborrow.com/items/create/ that SORT OF WORKED:) didnt tell me why, just shows the page now... so if i remove the debug setting it will show an error again right?

Comment: Honestly have no clue what you have done or are trying to do.. There seems to be all kind of errors on your site..

Comment: all im trying to do is get that page to display when debugging is off... what other errors do you see other than the userrating?

Comment: Uhm, try submitting the form for starters.. And try going to your main page..

Comment: yes i know the form doesnt work.. the page doesnt even DISPLAY yet without the bug... once i know how to create a new page, i will work on the form... and the main page is what i meant by the userrating... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating a new page, you need to set debug to >0, because otherwise it won't regenerate the cache, and the cached file won't have the new action.  You can also just delete the cache manually (delete the files under app/tmp/cache, off of the top of my head).  Setting it to '1' won't do most debug stuff, but will regenerate model files.  So when you set debug to look at it, it re-generated the cached file and worked.

So new rule: when you create new actions or models, set debug to 1 or clear the cache before trying to do anything with it.

Comment: ver interesting- had no idea... im still getting the feedback message from the add page not the create page so i think something is still wrong in my controller file

Comment: What feedback message are you getting/looking for?  And just turning debug on once should regenerate the cache, the page should still display after turning it off.